# AWS my PC can connect to RDS but EC2 can't

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rds, vpc

I've confused about to connect RDS from EC2. I don't understand why my PC(Mysql Workbench) can connect but EC2 couldn't.

I searched, read, tried a lot of articles to handle this problem but I failed.

*EC2 and RDS are in the same VPC and I checked security group, flow log that the packet was accepted.*

*All of outbound is allow to anywhere (security group, ACL)*

This is EC2

[image]

This is RDS

[image]

This is Security group

[image]

This is VPC info.

[image]

This is ACL

[image]

This is Route table.

[image]

This is the error from ec2

[image]

This is attempting to connect to RDS log from ec2

[image]

This accept flow log from cloudwatch.

[image]

I dont't know what's wrong with this.
Could you please help me?

**EDIT:**

This is ACL outbound.

[image]

Comment: Can you show your outbound rules for the network ACL? _Network ACLs are stateless; responses to allowed inbound traffic are subject to the rules for outbound traffic (and vice versa)._

Comment: @jogold I added!